# Will SharePoint 2013 support multiple values for External Data column?

Tags: external-data-column

It's been answered before that SharePoint 2010 does not support "allow multiple selections" on an External Data column. However, does anyone know if SharePoint 2013 will support this feature out of the box? Specifically, I would like to know if it will be possible to check "allow multiple selections" on the column settings for an External Data column (or will undesirable workarounds that defeat the main benefit of Business Connectivity Services, from my perspective, still be required...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not look like it (tested on RTM):
[image: screenshot of external column]
as there is no seemingly no option to choose it.
I do not know if it might be controlled by the model, but I don't think so.